# Principal Shared Amongst Threads

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using Spring OAuth2. I've configured a `ResourceServer` as below. When concurrent calls are made to the service, multiple threads *incorrectly* share the same principal. Is the configuration causing the principal to be shared? If not, any ideas on what could be the cause?

```
EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .headers()
        .contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self'")
        .and()
        .frameOptions()
        .deny()
        .and()
        .requestMatchers()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, PERMISSIBLE_PATHS).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
  }

  @Bean
  public PrincipalExtractor principalExtractor() {
    return map -> map.get(USER_CLAIM);
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthoritiesExtractor authoritiesExtractor() {
    return map -> AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(
        ((List<String>) map.get(GROUP_CLAIMS)).stream()
            .map(group -> String.format("ROLE_%s", group.toUpperCase()))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));

  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, your client send different access tokens? Did you configure anything more than you already showed?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the client is sending different access tokens. I configured a custom permission evaluator - I can share that if it would be helpful.